# Regarding dynamic data in panel control in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to display dynamic text on a panel control (in the form of notices and circulars in a website) from database table..How can i do it?
I am in a confusion regarding how to fetch data from table and display it dynamically on the panel...

Answer (score 0):

Go with repeater, datalist or gridview. Rest work you will have to do from design.

Comment: Gridview is going to show or display the data in a tabular format.But,what I want here is displaying data in a motion form over the panel..So,please help in this regard

Comment: Use repeater and make marquee to scroll or add jquery for animation